# Add sequential numbers to the beginning of the file names in folder

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a lot of files in a folder and I want to add sequential numbers to the beginning of every file in this folder. I also want that files are ordered by their size, not in alphabetic order.

For example: file "something.mp3" should be renamed to "01 - something.mp3" if it's the biggest file in the folder. I want to do that on Windows.

Comment: nice idea. Tell us, when you're done.

Comment: You tagged this with bash, are you asking for a Bash solution or a Window cmd only?

Comment: I would like to do that on Windows if it's possible. If it's not I would like to do it in Bash.

Comment: SO is not a place to put work orders and expect them to be done. That's not the way SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -1S | awk '{print "mv \"" $0 "\" \""NR "_" $0"\";"}' | bash
```

However the parsing `ls` output is discouraged. Use this only if you know your filenames do not contain any abnormal characters. [Read more here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Your solution works perfectly in Bash, thank you! I ran it on Windows with Git CMD.

Answer (score 2):

Bash:

```
I=0; for FILE in `ls -S`; do mv $FILE "$I - $FILE"; I=$((I+1)); done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your OS might list files alphabetically, I recommend using `printf` at some point (This will generate "0001 - file1.mp3", "0002 - file2.mp3", etc.). To change the number of padding 0's, use another digit in printf %0**4**d.

```
N=1  
while read -r file
do
  mv "$file" "$(printf %04d $N) - $file"
  N=$((N+1))
done < "$(ls -S)"
```

(or use `"$(ls -rS)"` if you want a reverse sort (biggest to smallest).

Comment: I tried to run this with batch script but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR` command can be used in a batch file to determine file size:

```
for %%F in (*.mp3) do echo [%%F] is [%%~zF] bytes
```

You'd have some work to do to get it to sort properly, though, since size 10 comes before size 2 in a text sort.

The `DIR` command can be used to list the files in size order:

```
dir /os *.mp3
dir /o-s *.mp3
dir /b /o-s *.mp3 > filesbysize.txt
```

Then you could use `FOR /F` to read that file and start doing your rename logic.

The `SET /A` command can be used to perform integer mathematics, so you could find a way to increment a counter in order to determine that prefix you want.

Be prepared to play around with each of these commands.  The learning curve isn't bad, but it isn't zero.

Good luck!